# Change element style without calling render method

Tags: reactjs, components, render

I would like to create React app where you import, move and resize images on the screen and then export their positions.  My idea was that I would have image as a component that would have its own attributes like positions, width, height and source. The problem is that I don't want to render new image element every time the component change its state (position, size, etc.) since it can be slow to load the image. I just want to change its style. Is there some React fashion approach how to do it? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe for your problem might be usefull to look life cycle update component...because it gives you some certain pattern to re-render a component in your own way..try to read something on "**componentShouldUpdate()**" this method give you a way to re-render the component only certain condition.
maybe here might be right for you: https://www.toptal.com/react/optimizing-react-performance

My best

Comment: Thank you! It helped.